# loading a responsestream into an XDocument, root element is missing

Tags: c#, stream, linq-to-xml

I have read that setting the position of the stream to 0 resolves this, but this fails as the stream "does not support seek operations".

It fails on this:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(resp.GetResponseStream());
```

Reading the stream:

```
string t = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.Default).ReadToEnd();
```

...reveals that my xml could not be any simpler:

```
<xml version="1.0">
  <ActiveStorms>
  </ActiveStorms>
</xml>
```

Is this somehow malformed?

Thanks for any help,
Mike

Answer (score 1):

XML documents do not end with a `</xml>` closing tag so delete that.  The initial `<xml version="1.0">` should be: `<?xml version="1.0">` (note the question mark).

So a valid version would look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0">
<ActiveStorms>
</ActiveStorms>
```

Answer (score 0):

The right XML declaration is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
```

and after that add your root node `<ActiveStorms>`
so,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ActiveStorms>
</ActiveStorms>
```